# ¿Por qué al abrir un .xlsx que contiene una imagen y lo guardo con otro nombre, pierdo la imagen en el nuevo .xlsx?

Tags: python, excel, imagen

¿Por qué al abrir un .xlsx que contiene una imagen a través de "`load_workbook`" de "`openpyxl`" y lo guardo con otro nombre, pierdo la imagen en el nuevo .`xlsx`?

```
# LIBRERIAS
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import os

wb = load_workbook(os.getcwd() + "\\Excel_Img.xlsx")
wb.save(os.getcwd() + "\\output.xlsx")
```

Comment: Intenta hacer una copia exacta de la hola o del libro, a ver que resultados obtienes. Tambien intenta insertar la imagen desde una ruta, a la hoja del libro excel.

Comment: Por desgracia openpyxl ahora mismo no puede leer imágenes insertadas en un xlsx ([ver documentación](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/2.5/usage.html#read-an-existing-workbook)), si que puedes agregarlas en cambio.

Answer (score 0):

Lamentablemente, en [esta documentación](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) oficial del proyecto openpyxl, podemos ver que dice:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir:

> openpyxl actualmente no lee todos los ítems de un archivo Excel, las
>   imágenes y los gráficos se perderán al leer un archivo y salvarlo con
>   otro nombre.

Comment: Son el templo del saber... Gracias a todos..